# I have an array with an amount of 13 in an adapter How can I get max value from my array

Tags: java, android

```
public class Adapter1 extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

// Keep all Images in array
public  Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.img1,
        R.drawable.img2,
        R.drawable.img3,
        R.drawable.img4,
        R.drawable.img5,
        R.drawable.img6,
        R.drawable.img7,
        R.drawable.img8,
        R.drawable.img9,
        R.drawable.img10,
        R.drawable.img11,
        R.drawable.img12,
        R.drawable.img13
};
```

Comment: This is an `Array` of resource Ids . What you mean by Max value here ? `mThumbIds[mThumbIds.length-1]` will give you the last element of array.

Comment: provide more info

Answer (score 0):

you can max value of array by :

```
mThumbIds[mThumbIds.length-1]
```

If you wants size of array, use it :

```
mThumbIds.length
```

Comment: @Andi Asvin Mahersatillah Surad upvote if it helps!!